# How do you keep toast bulma after redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, bulma

From the title itself. Yes, How do you keep alive the toast of bulma after redirection of page? Currently my code for saving data with toast of bulma is working fine. But what I'm trying to achieve is to maintain the toast after redirection.

Here's my ajax code for saving data:

```
$.ajax({
                        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        url: "{{ route('payNow') }}",
                        method: "POST",
                        data:{payNow: "TRUE"}, 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(data.success.length > 0){
                                // getDtls();
                                window.location = "//mydomain/reseller/transaction_history";
                                bulmaToast.toast({ message: data.success[0],
                                                   dismissible: true,
                                                   duration: 3000,
                                                   pauseOnHover: true,
                                                   animate: { in: "fadeIn", out: "fadeOut" },
                                                   type: "is-success" });
                            }else{
                                bulmaToast.toast({ message: data.error[0],
                                                   dismissible: true,
                                                   duration: 3000,
                                                   pauseOnHover: true,
                                                   animate: { in: "fadeIn", out: "fadeOut" },
                                                   type: "is-danger" });
                            }

                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

As you can see I coded first the `window.location` before `bulmaToast` to expect that the web will redirect first and show the `toast` effect.

The toast shows successfully but the displaying of toast is too fast because of the redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't show the toast properly because the code has already begun the transition to the next page.  If you want the toast to show on the next page, you'll need to [flash the toast into the session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data) before the transition, or show the toast on the current page with a setTimeout callback to the window.location.